# What is the meaning of the suffix -ox as in ferox?

Tags: adjective, suffixes

I have found different explanations for the meaning, but they all seem contradictory.

1. It shows exaggeration of an existing adjective (atrōx < āter)
2. It shows exaggeration of an existing verb (fĕrox < feriō)
3. It means 'having such an appearance', akin to eye, oculus and -opsis (celōx < celer)
4. It means 'having a stronger tendency towards something than the original adjective shows' (fĕrox < fērus)

Answer (score 4):

Morphologically, it should be fer-ok-s (spelled ferox), -s being the nominative singular ending, and the suffix is actually -ok- (spelled -oc-) here.

The OLD (Oxford Latin Dictionary) says the following:

" **-ox** -ōcis *adjl. suff* Forms adjs. denoting appreance, as Gk *βο-ῶπ-ις*, (*atrox, ferox*); also in wider sense, perh. w. different origins (*uelox*)."

cf. [Weiss 2020:](http://www.beechstave.com/weiss.html) 326

"ferōx 'fierce' (Plaut.+) < 'wild-looking' (ferus 'wild')" with the suffix -ōk-, "originally a root noun from the verbal root *h₃okʷ- 'see, look.' Cf Gk. γλαυκ-ώψ 'with gleaming eyes,' βο-ῶπ-ισ 'ox-eyed'" (cf. Leumann et al. 1977: 377, section 329.4)

[Ernout and Meillet](https://www.klincksieck.com/livre/735-dictionnaire-etymologique-de-la-langue-latine) are more cautious and say "peut-être" (maybe; [s.v. atrox](https://archive.org/details/DictionnaireEtymologiqueDeLaLangueLatine/page/n35/mode/2up)), citing [Schmidt  1889](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/g/genpub/ajc8774.0001.001/399?page=root;rgn=full%20text;size=100;view=image) (for Ancient Greek data?).

cf. [Walde and Hofmann](https://www.winter-verlag.de/en/detail/c3077/Walde_Alois_Lateinisches_etymologisches_Woerterbuch/) [s.v. atrox](https://archive.org/details/walde/page/n109/mode/2up).

[de Vaan](https://brill.com/view/title/12612) adds that "This can be disputed, but I see no better source for this suffix" ([s.v. ferus](https://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=latin&id=la0564)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!